# How to get access token using oauth_consumer_key in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento2.2

**Query 1.** 
Trying to get access token in magento 2 (I'm following magento doc http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0//get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html). I have oauth_consumer_secret=>vxwh416ltetobfo1ql745wjgw3in5wo0
store_base_url=>http://127.0.0.1/magento2-2.2.1/
oauth_verifier=>ewyaa6da6619pom8i8u5dkbbcjrc5vb0

please let me know how to get access token using these data.

**Query 2.** how to manage callback url after 3rd-party login screen to magento system and at the end save access token at 3rd-party application server, so that he will able to access magento API resource.

Also suggest me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Thanks in advance.